# Are saisons a high or a low alcohol beer?

Tags: beer-styles, saison

I just read the copy in this Northern Brewer [saison kit](http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/allgrain/AG-Saison.pdf) which says "Saisons are brewed hoppy and fairly strong in order to keep through the summer".  I had always thought that, as a farmhouse ale, saisons are a low-alcohol beer brewed for consumption by farmhands.  Though now that I think about it, I'm not sure I've ever had a modern saison lower than 5 or 6 percent, which has me doubting the low-alcohol provenance.

Which is it?  And if it's traditionally low-alcohol, why are modern saisons not so?

Comment: Not sure if Saisons followed the same path, but virtually all the traditional English beers went from "strong" ABV's (6-9%) down to fairly weak (3-5%) during the war rationing. Even styles like Brown ale and Mild ale used to be fairly strong by today's standards. Its likely that Saisons followed a similar fate, starting out strong, but getting weaker as wheat got rationed during war time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Farmhouse Ales" (Markowski, Brewers Publications) confirms that traditionally saison – while, yes, brewed in the winter or spring and needing to keep until the summer – obtained what preservation they did have from hops, not alcohol.  It also mentions that sourness was an accepted part of saison (and in fact many beer styles :) until relatively recently.

It also mentions pre-1900 OGs around 1.025-1.036, around-1900's OGs of 1.040-1.050, rising later to 14°P (1.057).  Even though saison is a very high-attenuating style, 90% attenuation of 1.050 only results in 6% abv.

Modern beers are strong because it's easier and less costly to make moderate-/high-alcohol beer, and generic "stylistic inflation" across all styles and categories.

Answer (score 5):

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saison) article on Saison is not terribly helpful. In one paragraph it states that traditionally, saison beers were less than 3% alcohol:

> originally saisons were meant to be refreshing and thus had alcohol levels less than 3%

In the very next paragraph, it says

> The ale had to be strong to prevent spoilage during the long storage

Strong or weak? Which is it?

The Brew Your Own [article](http://www.byo.com/stories/beer-styles/article/indices/11-beer-styles/1373-saison-style-profile) on Saison is interesting but doesn't get much into the history of the style.

The BJCP [guidelines](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style16.php#1c) permit alcohol levels between 5 and 7% ABV.

The thing to keep in mind is that the notion of beer styles is a modern one. Historically, brewers did not attempt to make beer that conformed to a style. Particular regions produced characteristic beers, but that was due mainly to ingredients that came readily to hand, water profile, climate, etc.

As to why no one brews a 3% ABV Saison any more, my guess is that it's simply the case that stronger beers sell better.